# Linear combination of a character

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra, characters, semi-simple-rings

Hi there I am trying to solve a problem about characters of a finite group $G$. If $\chi$ is a character such that $\langle \chi,\chi \rangle = 2$ and $\chi_1,\dotsc,\chi_n$ the irreducible characters of $G$ we need to find $\chi$ as an $\mathbb{N}$-linear combination of $\chi_i$'s. I thought of taking the inner product $\langle \chi,\chi \rangle$ but I can't continue further. Then maybe with orthogonality relations but I don't have enough for this. Any ideas? I am sorry if this is a bad question but I just started studying non-commutative algebra. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I fixed the formulas (please use $\LaTeX$ next time). Is my interpretation of the "N-linear combination" correct?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg thanks for your edit, yes it is correct!

Comment: Oh I think I get it, so to continue I take the nth root of 2 to use all the irreducible characters?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg It is not since $\chi=\sqrt2\cdot\chi_1$ is not a character. To be $\chi$ a character it must be an $\mathbb N$-linear combination of some irreducible characters.

Comment: @Deif thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only you can deduce is that $\chi=\chi_i+\chi_j$ for some $1\leq i\not=j\leq n$.
If we write $\chi=\sum_{i=1}^nn_i\chi_i$ for some nonnegative integers $n_i$ then, since $\langle \chi,\chi \rangle=2$ it follows that
$$2=\langle \chi,\chi \rangle=\langle\sum_{i=1}^nn_i\chi_i,\sum_{j=1}^nn_j\chi_j\rangle=\sum_{i,j=1}^nn_in_j\langle\chi_i,\chi_j\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^nn_i^2.$$
This implies that there are only two nonzero coefficients, say $n_i,n_j$ (with $i\not=j$), with value $1$ and that all the other coefficients are necessarily $0$.
Hence the claim follows.

Comment: Maybe my thought is wrong but since we only have 2 coefficients with value 1 that means that G would be abelian? And it would be isomorphic to a product of 2 cyclic groups?

Comment: Not necessarily. These coefficients don't tell information about $G$. Consider any nontrivial group $G$. Since $G$ has at least two conjugacy classes it follows that $G$ has also at least two different irreducible characters, say $\mu$ and $\psi$. Now, $\chi=\mu+\psi$ is a character of $G$ such that $\langle\chi,\chi\rangle=2$, but $G$ is an arbitrary group, not necessarily abelian or isomorphic to a product of $2$ cyclic groups.